# How to set auto hight of page for POS software by MPDF in Yii

Tags: yii, mpdf

I am facing a problem when printing pos invoice by MPDF. I don't want to set a fixed height of pdf page. Page height will be adjusted by its content. Here the line of my controller's function from where I am calling MPDF.

```
$mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('',array('80','130'), 8, '', 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 'P');
```

Please give me some idea how to get expected page size.

Answer (score 0):

pls try this

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('c', 'A4', 0, 'Arial', 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

OR

```
$mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('', 'A5');
```

Comment: Don't work it bro. It takes fixed page size (width & height) of A5 format.

Comment: @Fourkan how did solve this would greatly appreciate your assistance :)